# dpkg seems to be broken: command not found

Tags: dpkg

Tested on two 18.04 installs, while trying to install printer drivers and a few other packages. (Also see **EDIT** below)

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all  LPR_mfcj4620dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
sudo: dpkg -i --force-all : command not found

sudo /usr/bin/dpkg -V LPR_mfcj4620dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
sudo: /usr/bin/dpkg -V LPR_mfcj4620dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb: command not found
```

Testing with:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Command completes OK, but no messages

This works:

```
sudo dpkg --help:
```

But the moment I add any command line options, I get "Command not found".

$PATH=
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

**Edit....** 
I tried other packages and they worked.
So I re-downloaded the deb from the source.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all  LPR_mfcj4620dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
sudo: dpkg -i --force-all : command not found
```

Then a few seconds later, with no other changes - it worked:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all  LPR_mfcj4620dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
(Reading database ... 230357 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack LPR_mfcj4620dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb ...
Unpacking mfcj4620dwlpr:i386 (3.0.1-1) over (3.0.1-1) ...
Stopping printer spooler: lpd.
Starting printer spooler: lpd.
Setting up mfcj4620dwlpr:i386 (3.0.1-1) ...
Stopping printer spooler: lpd.
Starting printer spooler: lpd.
```

dpkg is not giving me any meaningful output if there is a problem with the actual file

In fact, this is very odd - inconsistent behaviour:

```
sudo dpkg -i nonexistentfile
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'nonexistentfile': No such file or directory
```

But:

```
sudo dpkg -i  nonsensename
sudo: dpkg -i: command not found

sudo dpkg -i  thursday
sudo: dpkg -i: command not found
```

Also interesting, when using filename completion, dkpg will not expand the filename if the test results in a command not found error. But will do so with a valid package. This almost suggests a problem with the shell.

Comment: Are you copy-pasting this from somewhere?

Comment: Originally, yes, but to eliminate that I worked within the shell. So copying/pasting from ls results within exact same shell (to save typing errors).   PS I've made an edit in the last few minutes

Comment: So this happens even if you type out every single character in the command line?

Comment: Yes. All the above after "Edit" was typed character by character.

Comment: wild guess here: are you typing this from an OSX terminal and happen to type alt-space accidentally (which would produce the unicode 0083 or "no break here" character, indistinguishable from space)